# merging mutiple arrays inside one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have an array full of full of arrays of one object

```
[[{id: 0, name: example1}], [{id: 1, name: example2}], [{id: 2, name: example3}]]
```

What I'm trying to do is to merge all of these array and make them look like this

```
[{id: 0, name: example1}, {id: 1, name: example2}, {id: 2, name: example3}]
```

I tried using concat but it still not working

```
let a=arr[0], b=arr[1], c=arr[2]
let d = a.concat(b,c)
console.log(d)
```

the arrays are still there

Comment: Not reproducible: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%5B%7B%20id%3A%200%2C%20name%3A%20'example1'%20%7D%5D%2C%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20'example2'%20%7D%5D%2C%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20'example3'%20%7D%5D%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20a%3Darr%5B0%5D%2C%20b%3Darr%5B1%5D%2C%20c%3Darr%5B2%5D%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20a.concat(b%2Cc)%0Aconsole.log(d)%0A

Answer (score 5):

Your code will flatten the three arrays, as you can see here:

```js
const arr = [[{id: 0, name: 'example1'}], [{id: 1, name: 'example2'}], [{id: 2, name: 'example3'}]]

let a=arr[0], b=arr[1], c=arr[2]

let d = a.concat(b,c)
console.log(d)
```

However, it's not scalable. If the array contains 6 items, you'll need to create 3 variables more, etc...

Another way to flatten the sub-arrays is by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const arr = [[{id: 0, name: 'example1'}], [{id: 1, name: 'example2'}], [{id: 2, name: 'example3'}]];

const result = [].concat(...arr);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

flattening the array is the right way to go, pass the array to this:

```
function flattenDeep(arr1) {
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
```

You can use lodash for this also:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.flattendeep

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays.

```
let a=arr[0][0], b=arr[1][0], c=arr[2][0]
let d = [a, b, c]
console.log(d)
```

Comment: @zerkms it would have made it easier if you supplied a working piece of code yourself, to be honest, e.g., the initial arrays. It's hard to work with pseudo-code ;-)

Comment: It's not me who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [[{id: 0, name: 'example1'}], [{id: 1, name: 'example2'}], [{id: 2, name: 'example3'}]]

output = input.map(([firstElementOfArray]) => firstElementOfArray)

console.log(output)
```